# How do I write a regexp to capture two rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need help with a regular expression.
I have the following text:

```
Revision: 42064
Author: dbratilov
Date: 19 июля 2013 г. 13:29:43
Message:
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
TA55.1 obly for KM partyUId  

----
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5454
```

I need to catch all that appears between the `[BUG]` tag and the symbols `----`.

```
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
TA55.1 obly for KM partyUId
```

I wrote this regexp:

```regex
^(\W+)(BUG+)(.*+)
```

And the result is:

```
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
```

I can't capture the second row. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I highly recommend using http://rubular.com to test patterns. See http://rubular.com/r/P8fW5oE2Jk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
text = 'Revision: 42064
Author: dbratilov
Date: 19 июля 2013 г. 13:29:43
Message:
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
TA55.1 obly for KM partyUId  

----
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5454
'
text =~ /^(\[BUG\].+$\n.+)$/

captures:

  $1 # => "[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144\nTA55.1 obly for KM partyUId  "
```

`$1` is the short-hand for the first captured group in the pattern. http://rubular.com/r/A862gWfkvp

The same thing could be accomplished using:

```
text[/^(\[BUG\].+$\n.+)$/, 1]
"[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144\nTA55.1 obly for KM partyUId  "
```

which takes advantage of String's [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method and its ability to accept a pattern and return a single capture-group from it.

Changing the pattern to:

```
/^(\[BUG\].+)(?=^---)/m
```

extends the capture from `[BUG]` to the line before `----`. The `m` flag tells the regex engine to capture `"\n"` like a normal character with `.` (any-character). In this case, the pattern means "capture everything from `^[BUG]` to just before `^----`.

```
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
TA55.1 obly for KM partyUId 
foo
```

In the Rubular page I added a `foo` line to make it obvious that's being captured too.
http://rubular.com/r/dtQx48UcQb

Answer (score 3):

Use [regex multiline modifier](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes):

```
s = 'Revision: 42064
Author: dbratilov
Date: 19 июля 2013 г. 13:29:43
Message:
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
TA55.1 obly for KM partyUId  

----
Modified : /Analitics/Документы/ЧТЗ/BR-5454'

# Note the m at the and of the regex
puts s.scan /^\W+BUG+.*?^----$/m #=>
[BUG] By VTBSOARVIIIS-2144
TA55.1 obly for KM partyUId
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
\[BUG\](?>[^\n]++|\n(?!\n-{4}))+
```

The idea is to use `\n\n----` as end limit for the target string. To do it, you must describe the content like this:

```
(?>     # open a group (atomic here, since recording backtrack positions is not needed)
[^\n]++ # all that is not a newline, one or more time (possessive for the same reason)
|       # OR
\n(?!\n-{4}) # or a newline not followed by "\n----"
)+      # repeat the group one or more times
```

The interest is to obtain a performant pattern with very few backtracks and avoid the dotall problem.